# VB.net use custom control

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to use the custom GenericDatagridview

[(which I got here)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14674/Generic-DataGridView-V)

I have added the dll to my toolbox. It is also referenced in my project properties. However when I run my application. The form with the new control gives the following error : The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

The code for the form load is :

```
Imports GenericDataGridView
Public Class GenericDGVTRASHFRM
    Private Sub GenericDGVTRASHFRM_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'SkeduleringsDatabasis6DataSet.Blokkeklaar' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.BlokkeklaarTableAdapter.Fill(Me.SkeduleringsDatabasis6DataSet.Blokkeklaar)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Regards.

Comment: Are either of these "SkeduleringsDatabasis6DataSet" "Blokkeklaar" nothing when the form loads?

Comment: Hi Andrew and thank you for responding. What do you mean with "nothing"? The database table has information in it.  Regards

Comment: I mean have you instantiated SkeduleringsDatabasis6DataSet and SkeduleringsDatabasis6DataSet.Blokkeklaar by the time the form loads? Do those objects exist and contain data / values when the form loads?

Comment: Hi Andrew. I have added the following line below the last line in my form load (see code in my question) : Me.SkeduleringsDatabasis6DataSet = New DataSet(). Still the error. Obviously I am have not instantiated correctly. How do I do that? Regards